# Making previous view controller visible in next viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I have one view controller with name Parent.

I had pushed Child View controller from Parent.

I want to make ABC visible from Child. Alpha and opacity of Child done. But how to make previous view controller visible after `pushViewController`. Or is it necessary to "Add Child as a subview to Parent" for the same?

Comment: Do you want view previous view controller partially?

Comment: You can do it by addSubview but for pushViewController you should search some thirdparty library

Comment: @Kavya:Yes.. _baydi 1:Yes,I'm searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please give some more declaration . can't understand your question properly. 
If you want to set alfa of ABCView controller from childviewcontroller then ,
It is easy Just set method like

// in your abcview controller

```
 -(void)setalfa { // here set alfa of your ABCViewcontroller like 
     self.view.alpha = set alfa of abc

 }
```

and call this method from childview controller, where you want to set alfa of abcviewcontroller
FOr Example :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   abcviewcontroller *abc = [[abcviewcontroller alloc]init];
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [abc setalfa]; // here your alfa will be set of another view controller

    }
```

Comment: have one view controller with name Parent.I had pushed Child View controller from Parent.I want to make ABC visible from Child.Alpha and opacity of Child done.But how to make previous view controller visible after pushViewController..Or is it necessary to "Add Child as subview from Parent"for the same?Currently it is showing child's main view color as backgroung.

Comment: both are `viewcontrollers` or only `view`and both are different ? can you please edit pic of your storyboard ?

Comment: Parent and child are two different view controller and subcless of UIViewController..Can't take pic..Against company policy..:( Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
if(forgotPasswordViewController == nil)
{
    forgotPasswordViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ISForgotPasswordViewController"];
    forgotPasswordViewController.delegate = self;
    [ISCommon addTransitionAnimationOfType:kCATransitionFade andSubType:kCATransitionFromRight forLayer:self.view.layer                                 forDuration:0.50 onTarget:nil];
    forgotPasswordViewController.view.frame = [self.view bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:forgotPasswordViewController.view];
```

//        [forgotPasswordViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }